# Visitor pattern (from bottom to top)

Tags: python, design-patterns, python-2.7, visitor-pattern

Please consider the (example) code below before I get to my specific question regarding `visitor pattern` in `python`:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self):
        self.children = []
    def add(self, node):
        self.children.append(node)
    def check(self):
        print("Node")
        return True
    def accept(self, visitor):
        visitor.visit(self)

class NodeA(Node):
    def check(self):
        print("NodeA")
        return True
class NodeB(Node):
    def check(self):
        print("NodeB")
        return True


class NodeA_A(NodeA):
    def check(self):
        print("NodeA_A")
        return True
class NodeA_B(NodeA):
    def check(self):
        print("NodeA_B")
        return True

class NodeA_A_A(NodeA_A):
    def check(self):
        print("NodeA_A_A")
        return False

class NodeRunner:
    def visit(self, node):
        node.check()
        if len(node.children) > 0:
            for child in node.children:
                child.accept(self)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    n = Node()
    n1 = NodeA()
    n2 = NodeB()
    n11 = NodeA_A()
    n12 = NodeA_B()
    n111 = NodeA_A_A()

    n.add(n1)
    n.add(n2)

    n1.add(n11)
    n1.add(n12)

    n11.add(n111)

    v = NodeRunner()
    v.visit(n)
```

When I run it, it traverse all the nodes-classes iteratively and returns the following:

```
Node
NodeA
NodeA_A
NodeA_A_A
NodeA_B
NodeB
```

This is all fine but now to my question. You may have noticed that each `check`-method returns a Boolean (lets say this is a complicated method in reality).

In the example above every `check`-method inside `Node` classes return `True` except `NodeA_A_A`. I would like to store this somehow during visiting so I can fail all the base classes.

This is hard to explain let me illustrate:

- if `NodeA_A_A` returns `False`, then I would like to fail `NodeA_A, NodeA and Node`. regardless of what these classes return.
- if `NodeB` returns `False`, then I would like to fail `Node`. regardless of what other classes return.

So if a `child-class` is somewhere failing (check method returns `False`), I would like to fail all its base classes.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by `base classes`? Is it `children` or `parents` or the real classes?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: @User By 'Bases Classes' I mean the classes that has been inherited! e.g. NodeA inherits from Node, Node is its base class.

Comment: Does it really have anything to do with Visitor/ Composite Pattern really? Ok you have the Composite structure and you add operations using Visitor. But for me what you really need is additionally the State pattern to make the behaviour dependent on some 'shared' state.

Comment: I've always seen the visitor pattern as a poor-man's version of multiple dispatch (specifically double-dispatch). You're not using Java or C#, you're using Python, which is dynamic and has support for multimethods (through [multimethods](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/multimethods) or [PEAK-rules](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PEAK-Rules)). So, why are you using visitors? (P.S. I'd be happy to hear anyone else's opinion on the subject too. I can't think of a good reason to use a visitor in Python, but I'd like to understand if there is a good use case for this.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the visitor pattern to visit all the nodes.
One visitor visits and runs all the nodes, the other visitor bubbles up the result.
The code and output is provided below:

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.children = []
        self.result = None
    def add(self, node):
        self.children.append(node)
    def check(self):
        self.result = True
        print "Node: result:%s" % self.result
        return self.result
    def accept(self, visitor):
        visitor.visit(self)

class Node_A(Node):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Node_A, self).__init__()
    def check(self):
        self.result = True
        print "Node_A: result:%s" % self.result
        return self.result

class Node_A_A(Node_A):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Node_A_A, self).__init__()
    def check(self):
        self.result = True
        print "Node_A_A: result:%s" % self.result
        return self.result

class Node_A_B(Node_A):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Node_A_B, self).__init__()
    def check(self):
        self.result = True
        print "Node_A_B: result:%s" % self.result
        return self.result

class Node_A_A_A(Node_A_A):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Node_A_A_A, self).__init__()
    def check(self):
        self.result = True
        print "Node_A_A_A: result:%s" % self.result
        return self.result
class Node_A_A_B(Node_A_A):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Node_A_A_B, self).__init__()
    def check(self):
        self.result = False
        print "Node_A_A_B: result:%s" % self.result
        return self.result

class Node_A_B_A(Node_A_B):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Node_A_B_A, self).__init__()
    def check(self):
        self.result = True
        print "Node_A_B_A: result:%s" % self.result
        return self.result



class NodeRunner:
    def visit(self, node):
        if len(node.children) > 0:
            for child in node.children:
                child.accept(self)
        node.check()

class NodeChecker:
    def visit(self, node):
        results = []
        if len(node.children) > 0:
            for child in node.children:
                child.accept(self)
                results.append(child.result)
            node.result = all(results)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    node = Node()
    node_a = Node_A()
    node_a_a = Node_A_A()
    node_a_b = Node_A_B()

    node_a_a_a = Node_A_A_A()
    node_a_a_b = Node_A_A_B()

    node_a_b_a = Node_A_B_A()

    node.add(node_a)

    node_a.add(node_a_a)
    node_a_a.add(node_a_a_a)
    node_a_a.add(node_a_a_b)

    node_a.add(node_a_b)
    node_a_b.add(node_a_b_a)


    print("-------------------")
    nVisitor = NodeRunner()
    nVisitor.visit(node)
    print("-------------------")
    nVisitor = NodeChecker()
    nVisitor.visit(node)
    print("-------------------")
    print "node_a_a_a: result: %s" % node_a_a_a.result
    print "node_a_a_b: result: %s" % node_a_a_b.result
    print "node_a_a: result: %s" % node_a_a.result
    print "node_a_b_a: result: %s" % node_a_b_a.result
    print "node_a_b: result: %s" % node_a_b.result
    print "node_a: result: %s" % node_a.result
    print "node: result: %s" % node.result
```

The output is provided below:

```
-------------------
Node_A_A_A: result:True
Node_A_A_B: result:False
Node_A_A: result:True
Node_A_B_A: result:True
Node_A_B: result:True
Node_A: result:True
Node: result:True
-------------------
-------------------
node_a_a_a: result: True
node_a_a_b: result: False
node_a_a: result: False
node_a_b_a: result: True
node_a_b: result: True
node_a: result: False
node: result: False
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that what you are asking for is not about visitor patter, but about how to implement a depth-first search algorithm.  Here is my solution for your question:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self):
        self.children = []
    def add(self, node):
        self.children.append(node)
    def check(self):
        print("Node")
        return True
    def accept(self, visitor):
        return visitor.visit(self)

class NodeA(Node):
    def check(self):
        print("NodeA")
        return True
class NodeB(Node):
    def check(self):
        print("NodeB")
        return True


class NodeA_A(NodeA):
    def check(self):
        print("NodeA_A")
        return True
class NodeA_B(NodeA):
    def check(self):
        print("NodeA_B")
        return True

class NodeA_A_A(NodeA_A):
    def check(self):
        print("NodeA_A_A")
        return False

class NodeRunner:
    def visit(self, node):
        ret = True
        # visit all children
        for child in node.children:
            v = child.accept(self)
            if not v and ret:  # if some child not accepted, then we think that the parent node should also not be accepted
                ret = False

        # check the node
        if not node.check():
            ret = False
        return ret

if __name__ == "__main__":
    n = Node()
    n1 = NodeA()
    n2 = NodeB()
    n11 = NodeA_A()
    n12 = NodeA_B()
    n111 = NodeA_A_A()

    n.add(n1)
    n.add(n2)

    n1.add(n11)
    n1.add(n12)

    n11.add(n111)

    v = NodeRunner()
    print v.visit(n)
```

Comment: Hi, this is really not what I was looking for. Your code does not even visit all nodes. I want child-nodes to set the result of their base-classes and this should be done all the way up.

Comment: @theAlse So you want to have all the nodes visited, and when some child node fails to pass the check, the parent node's result will also be false. Have I got it right?